# Grouping in Mule to write to different files

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, mule, mule-studio

I'm using MuleStudio to pull data from a database using JDBC. I'd like to write to different XML files depending on the records. Is there any way to use an aggregator to do this?

My data looks like this -

```
<item>
  <name>Bob</name>
  <age>19</age>
  <color>blue</color>
</item>

<item>
   <name>Bob</name>
   <age>19</age>
   <food>pizza</food>
</item>
```

The flow runs once per record so would I need a custom aggregator to group based on name and age above? My output xml file should be like this

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <age>19</age>
    <color>blue</color>
    <food>pizza</food>
</item>
```

Comment: If the two items belong to the same database, wouldn't be easier to leverage database's capabilities to retrieve it already aggregated?

Comment: This would require some sort of grouping, so the query would take a lot of time to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use custom aggregator to combine based on group or you can also use Mule XSLT transformer to combine the fields and get your required XML.
I uess using XSLT will be easier for you to combine the fields and to get your required Xml format.
XSLT reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer
DataMapper will also be a good option if you use Mule enterprise edition